# OpenLayers: Running calculations on pixels within polygon

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers 4.6.5, I need to run some calculations on a TileImage source, but only for the pixels which sit within a polygon, and calculate some basic statistics for the polygon based on the results of these calculations.

The process I'm envisaging for each polygon would be as follows:

- For each pixel in polygon, calculate value of red band divided by green band
- Calculate average of all values calculated for all pixels in polygon
- Create new polygon layer containing a single polygon, identical in shape to the original polygon, but shaded with a colour based on the average value

This seems like a fairly straightforward task but I can't find anything online that discusses this kind of thing. I was hoping to find something along the lines of a "forEachPixelInFeature" method, but that doesn't seem to exist. I suspect the process will need to start with a step which first checks each pixel to determine whether or not it's within the polygon, but I can't find anything online which helps me with that either.

Please note that the polygons I'm working with are not regular rectangles, and so unfortunately any solution using simple rectangular bounding boxes won't work.

Would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pixels in the polygon like this

```
var geom = myFeature.getGeometry();
var size = map.getSize();
var pixels = [];
if (geom.intersectsExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent(size))) {
  for (var i=0; i<size[0]; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<size[1]; j++) {
      var coordinate = map.getCoordinateFromPixel([i,j]);
      if (geom.intersectsCoordinate(coordinate)) pixels.push([i,j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(pixels);
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I needed to get started. Thanks once again @Mike!